# How do I fix a pagination issue with Cake PHP where clicking "next page" displays the same news articles?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, web, pagination

This webpage I've been working on (BMAMedia.com/news) displays 20 articles at a time.  When "Next Page" is clicked, the site continues to display the same articles every time. My guess would be the issue lies in one of these three functions:

```
function index() {
    $this->News->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('news', $this->paginate());
}

function editlist() {   
    $this->layout = 'adminlayout';
    $this->News->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('news', $this->paginate());
}

function headlines() {
    $news = $this->paginate();
    if(isset($this->params['requested'])) {
        return $news;
    }
    $this->News->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('news', $news);
}
```

If someone could please help me with this that would be great because I'm not sure where to go from here and I've researched for hours with no luck.

Comment: The index function, the paginate array in the controller and the index template are the things that are relevant - please put them in the question. What version of CakePHP are you using? Given that `http://bmamedia.com/news/index?page=2` works - the problem is how you're generating the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I believe you need to do 

`$this->set('news', $this->paginate($this->News));
or 
$this->set('news', $this->paginate('News'))`; this is cake 1.3 if I am not mistaken so i don't recall as I haven't worked on it in a while, but I think you need to pass a variable in your paginate method.

Comment: `I believe you need to do` paginate with no args always just takes defaults, this isn't going to fix/change anything (also in 1.3 paginate only expects the name of a model):